# Ionic range slider does not work

Tags: ionic2, ionic3

I am using ionic 3.

Here is my code

```
<ion-range  dualKnobs="true"  min="$10" max="$100" color="secondary" >
              <ion-label range-left>$10</ion-label>
              <ion-label range-right>$100</ion-label>
 </ion-range>
```

But range slider does not work.

Kindly advice me,

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With dual knob slider you need to set an object as default value.

This should work-

**HTML:**

```
<ion-range  dualKnobs="true"  min="$10" max="$100" [(ngModel)]="rangeObject"  color="secondary" >
              <ion-label range-left>$10</ion-label>
              <ion-label range-right>$100</ion-label>
</ion-range>
```

**TS:**

```
public rangeObject:any= {lower: 0, upper: 100};
```

Comment: Thank u so much.It's wrk.: )